# print current directory in bash command inside cloud build yaml

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

So i want to print the current working directory after reading the git tag of the commit example :

```
/demo
/test
/prod
```

So when a tag contains **verxxx-demo** the inline script will know that it needs to switch to the specific folder.
My problem is now that i want to print the current path after the folder is switched and usually in linux you do it with pwd but in cloudbuild seems not to work or i am missing something .

```
if [[ $TAG_NAME == *test* ]]
        then
          cd org/test
          echo switched "($PWD)"
        elif [[ $TAG_NAME == *demo* ]]
        then
          cd org/demo
          echo switched folder
        else
          echo no tag
        fi
```

when i use this code , i get the next error in cloudbuild :

> **Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: generic::invalid_argument: invalid value for 'build.substitutions': key in the template "PWD" is not a valid built-in substitution**

Any suggestions how to tackle this one ? so i can print the current path after the change folder happens ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
echo "switched `pwd`"
```

based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4797).

I know the variable substitution can be tricky with cloudbuild, so please lmk if that doesn't work.